# Making scrolling icons stop at a div element instead of using scrollTop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently using this javascript function to fix my social media buttons to the header when the user scrolls down to them so they then start to scroll with the fixed header.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
     var $el = $('.social-icons'); 
     console.log($(this).scrollTop());

     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 925){ 
     $el.removeClass("not-fix-search");
     $el.addClass("fix-search");

     }
     if ($(this).scrollTop() < 925){
     $el.removeClass("fix-search");
     $el.addClass("not-fix-search");
     } 
     });
```

It works perfectly on my 27' monitor but on my smaller monitor it scrolls way past the header before it fixes, im wondering if i can make them switch the class when it hits the navbar div instead of using scrollTop?

html

```
   <div class="row social-icons not-fix-search" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:5px;">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" >
               <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/standsafe/', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: .5s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-01.png" alt="phoneicon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" style="">
               <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/standsafe?lang=en', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: 1s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-02.png" alt="phoneicon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
               <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/company/stand-safe-ltd/', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: 1.5s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-03.png" alt="phoneicon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" style="">
               <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com/standsafe/?hl=en', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: 2s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-04.png" alt="phoneicon">
            </div>

         </div>
```

Comment: Can u plz send me the html code?

Comment: ok no pbm.......

Comment: Added html not fixed the issue haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic height of the body or window.. See below example.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > ($(window).height()-100)) {
    $el.removeClass("not-fix-search");
    $el.addClass("fix-search"); 
}

if ($(this).scrollTop() < ($(window).height()-100)) {
    $el.removeClass("fix-search");
    $el.addClass("not-fix-search");
}
```

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var $el = $('.social-icons');
  console.log($(this).scrollTop());

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > ($(window).height()-100)) {
    $el.removeClass("not-fix-search");
    $el.addClass("fix-search");
  }

  if ($(this).scrollTop() < ($(window).height()-100)) {
    $el.removeClass("fix-search");
    $el.addClass("not-fix-search");
  }

});
```

```css
.main-container{
  height: 2000px;
}
.fix-search{
  position:fixed;
}
.not-fix-search{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="row social-icons not-fix-search" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:5px;">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
      <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/standsafe/', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: .5s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-01.png" alt="phoneicon">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" style="">
      <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/standsafe?lang=en', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: 1s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-02.png" alt="phoneicon">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
      <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/company/stand-safe-ltd/', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: 1.5s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-03.png" alt="phoneicon">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" style="">
      <img class="fadeIn animated socbutton hvr-shrink" onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com/standsafe/?hl=en', '_blank');" style="animation-delay: 2s;cursor: pointer;" src="assets/social/ectangle-04.png" alt="phoneicon">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/r4nu71ot/) also..

Answer (score -1):

Use `$el.scrollTop()` to get the offset of the element, not the window. You can do something like:

```
// headerHeight = the actual height of your header element
if ($el.scrollTop() <= headerHeight) {
    // add class
}
```